# Using ScaleType enum values by its integer reference

Tags: java, android, enums, scaletype

To make my question way clear, I want to use `ScaleType` in layout xml with different values according to layout width (e.g sw-600, sw-720, ...etc), and as it doesn't has a clear constant values like layout weights for example I don't know if it is possible to achieve that, so I had a look about [ImageView class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/ImageView.java#ImageView.ScaleType.0MATRIX) and found that the `ScaleType` values are `enum` with assigned values, so is it possible to use the enum its assigned values? so when use it in the xml it will be

```
android:scaleType="2" // 2 will be an Integer value assigned differently across different layouts
```

instead of:

```
android:scaleType="FIT_START"
```

Comment: `scaleType="2"`? why? what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: to have `scaleType="@integer/scale_type_value"` and then add this integer with different values in every integers file.

Comment: and what is wrong with values like "FIT_START"? why do you need integers?

Comment: I have the layout with different scaly types according to width, so I want to be able to have a lot of values assigned in each the integers file, are you know how to achieve that using values like `"FIT_START"`, and if you know, how to deal with it, is it considered as integers or dimens or Strings or what ?

Comment: sorry i completely have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: @pskink well, do you have the idea of having different values for a `layout_width` and this values are assigned each in its corresponding dimens file?!!  like `android:layout_width="@dimen/width_of_layout"`, its the same here but I want it with ScaleType not width

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat  I totally understand you as I'm trying to do the same thing. I want to have different scale type depending on the screen. Did you manage to get it working? I'm just trying to find the best way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: @Lancelot unfortunately no, I didn't manage to find a way to achieve that, so kindly if you reached anything in the future about that, tell me.

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat Hi, the way I've done it, and seems to be working. It's by using the Integer that correspond with each Enum. For example in the case of ScaleType if I want to use FitCenter I set it to 3. Something like this   <integer name="advert_scaletype">3</integer> and seems to be working. I can have different scale types based on my resource folders

Comment: @Lancelot in fact I tries this idea before but it didn't work with me.

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat Strange, have you tried again? Not sure what could be but I have an example where in tablet I use a type of scale and in the phone another one and seems to be working. I would have to try in other devices as well but so far so good.

Comment: @Lancelot you can add a complete answer if what you tried, may be you did something I didn't figure out

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat just done it, not sure why it doesn't work in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've done and so far so good. I have one resource that contains different values depending on the res folder type.

w720dp\sizes.xml

```
<integer name="advert_scaletype">3</integer>
```

values\sizes.xml

```
<integer name="advert_scaletype">6</integer>
```

By doing this I get different scale type on the image if I'm on tablet or phone.

The way I use it:

```
 <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/advert_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="@integer/advert_scaletype"
        android:transitionName="photo"/>
```

I haven't found any issues so far so not sure why this is not working for other people.

---

In the case of the value you want to use is **float**, you can store it inside `dimens.xml` in the following format:

```
<item name="advert_scaletype" format="float" type="dimen">7.6</item>
```

and then it will be like:

```
 <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView 
      ...
      android:scaleType="@dimens/advert_scaletype" />
```

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work in the first place when I tried it, but may be I was do something wrong. Now it's working perfectly.

Comment: by the way I put the values inside integers.xml instead of sizes.xml (won't make a difference but integers.xml is just commonly used to store such values)

Comment: I also added some additions to adapt with the float weightsum values

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before and I'm posting here what I think is the best approach so far:

***values\style.xml***

```
<style name="my_imageview_parent_style">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">match_parent</item>
</style>

<style name="my_imageview_child_style" parent="my_imageview_parent_style">
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
</style>
```

***values-XXX\style.xml***

```
<style name="my_imageview_child_style">
    <item name="android:scaleType">fitXY</item>
</style>
```

***values-YYY\style.xml***

```
<style name="my_imageview_child_style">
    <item name="android:scaleType">fitXY</item>
</style>
```

Comment: this answer can be considered also